# Is this a proper way of using AJAX with jQuery and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need some help. I'm going use AJAX (for the first time) and I'd like you to tell me whether the way I am going to show you is optimal.

Let's say that I have a select element.

```
<select class="update-db" data-id="25" data-original-value="2">
    <option value="1">Yellow</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

So here is what I do:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.update-db', function() {

// Get needed data
var select = $(this);
var id = select.attr('data-id');
var originalValue = select.attr('data-original-value');
var newValue = select.val();

    // Perform the request
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'update-db.php',
        data: { id: id, 'original-value': originalValue, 'new-value': newValue }
    });

  // Then, if everything is okay, change the "original value" of the select element
  // so that we can perform the updating operation again without having to refresh the page
  .done(function() {
      select.attr('data-original-value', newValue);
  });

});
```

Then, on the other side, a PHP script validates everything and updates the database.

Is this the correct way of using AJAX? I feel it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure [¯\\_(ツ)_/¯](http://jayblanchard.net/putting_it_all_together.html)

Comment: Why do you feel it is not the correct way? Does it do what you want it to? If so, it is correct. If it does not, then it is not correct.

Comment: It does what it is supposed to do. It's just that getting data from HTML attributes like that seems kind of incorrect. Maybe I'm just not used to it as I don't have any experience with JavaScript.

Comment: So you're looking for *standards and good practices* and not for *correct and functional behavior*.

Comment: Just remove the `;` after the `$.ajax()` in order to chain your `done()` method with it, and you'll be fine.